# How to take an element from an array list and assign it into another array list

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, methods

I have to create a program in java, which is based on an ordering system. I have the following classes : orders, orders list, supplier, supplier list, payment, payment list. The program is developed in javafx, and the user can create new orders, create suppliers, make payments for the orders based on the id of the order. But I can not figure out how to assign a supplier to an order.
The order has to specify what supplier it came from.

I will make screenshots of my code, I tried writing if else conditions and methods, but they do not work, so some help would be appreciated.

I have thought about storing suppliers in the list, and then try and modify the method that creates the order to ask for a supplier input based on the stored values, but I can not figure out how to do that.

this is the code for the creating orders with my attempt

```
static void addHandler(int noOfOrderNrIn, OrderList listIn,int noOfSupplierNrIn, SupplierList slistIn)
{
    
    
    System.out.println("Enter order number: ");
    int orderNrEntered = EasyScanner.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    String nameOrdEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
    
    System.out.println("Enter description: ");
    String descEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
    
    System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
    String quantityEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
    
    System.out.println("Enter supplier number: ");
    int  suppNrEntered = EasyScanner.nextInt();
    
    
    //Order o =  new Order(orderNrEntered, nameOrdEntered, descEntered, quantityEntered);
    //listIn.addOrder(o);
    //System.out.println("New order "   +  orderNrEntered +  " successfully added");
    System.out.println("Checking if the supplier exists: ");
    
    
    
    
    
    
 
    if(orderNrEntered < 1 || orderNrEntered > noOfOrderNrIn)
    {
        System.out.println ("There are only "  + noOfOrderNrIn  + " orders");
    } 
    else if(listIn.search(orderNrEntered) !=  null)
    {
        System.out.println("Order  "  + orderNrEntered  + " exists");
        System.out.println("Checking if the supplier exists: ");
    }
    else if(suppNrEntered< 1 || suppNrEntered > noOfSupplierNrIn)
    {
        System.out.println ("There are only "  + noOfSupplierNrIn  + " suppliers");
    }
    else if(slistIn.searchNr(suppNrEntered) !=  null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Supplier  "  + suppNrEntered  + " exists");
        Order o =  new Order(orderNrEntered, nameOrdEntered, descEntered, quantityEntered);
        listIn.addOrder(o);
        System.out.println("New order "     +  orderNrEntered +  " successfully added");
    }
    
    
}
```

this is the code to add suppliers, the code for adding orders was similar to this one before my attempt

```
  static void addHandler2(int noOfSupplierNrIn, SupplierList listIn)
  {
      
      System.out.println("Enter supplier number: ");
      int supplierNrEntered = EasyScanner.nextInt();
      
      System.out.println("Enter name: ");
      String nameSuppEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
      
      System.out.println("Enter Address: ");
      String addressEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
      
      System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
      String numberEntered = EasyScanner.nextString();
     
   
      if(supplierNrEntered < 1 || supplierNrEntered > noOfSupplierNrIn)
      {
          System.out.println ("There are only "  + noOfSupplierNrIn  + " suppliers");
      } 
      else if(listIn.searchNr(supplierNrEntered) !=  null)
      {
          System.out.println("Supplier  "  + supplierNrEntered  + " exists");
      }
      else  // ok to add an supplier
      {
          Supplier s =  new Supplier(supplierNrEntered, nameSuppEntered,addressEntered, numberEntered);
          listIn.addSupplier(s);
          System.out.println("New Supplier"     +  supplierNrEntered +  " successfully added");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Turing85 I do not get error codes, and I uploaded the images, if you click on the highlighted words. I do not know why, but that is how it let me upload them

Edit: ohh, okay wait a sec

Comment: Again, please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Turing85 Yes I have read it, sorry, my mistake, 2nd time here. Thank you for sending the link, I would not have known otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Does a supplier have to be assigned to an order when the order is created? Or can orders exist without suppliers and be added later?

If orders don't need to have a supplier right away, you can just make a method in your order class that assigns a passed supplier:

```java
public class Order {
    private Supplier orderSupplier;

    ...

    public void setSupplier(Supplier s) {
        this.orderSupplier = s;
    }
}
```

If suppliers are assigned at the point in time when orders are created then you can pass a supplier to an order through the order's constructor:

```java
public class Order {
    private Supplier orderSupplier;

    public Order(Supplier s)
        this.orderSupplier = s;
    }
}
```